# [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: Header at <App>

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, rendering, warnings, vuejs3

My component doesn't render and I get the above warning in the console. This is my first Vue project, so I am struggling to understand where the issue lies.

This is my App.vue:

```
<template>
  <Header />
</template>

<script>
import Header from "./components/Header";

export default {
  setup() {
    return {
      Header,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

And this is the Header component, I am trying to render, Header.vue:

```
<template>
  <header>
    <h1>Income Tracker</h1>
    <div class="total-income">€0</div>
  </header>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>
```

Any idea where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in Vue 2:

```js
<script>
import Header from "./components/Header";

export default {
  components {
    Header
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Great, thank you Nikola! Only missing the colon behind components, but it worked out